# Kotlin forEach return with label doesn't work

Tags: kotlin

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html) is written that we can interrupt `forEach` with label.

I tried it in my android app but failed, next I tried it with demo code just there on official page and that didn't work too!!

Can somebody explain why this code doesn't work and how to fix it?

```
fun foo() {
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach lit@{
    if (it == 3) return@lit // local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop
    print(it)
}
print(" done with explicit label")
```

}

wrong result:

```
1245 done with explicit label
```

**Edit:**
Only after reading answers I realised that the answer there is on that page but only at the end:

```
Note that the use of local returns in previous three examples is similar to the use of continue in regular loops
```

So, I was sure that earlier they are talking about `break`, not `continue`.
It would be better to put this note before the examples on the page so as not to be misleading, but anyway the best answer is to use `takeWhile`

Comment: The article you linked explains why this actually _is_ the expected result, and it also includes the solution for the behavior I believe you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Every time I see these label questions, I'm more convinced they were a bad idea and it's best to just avoid them.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip They need to hurry and add break and continue for inline lambdas. They said they planned to years ago and the workaround is ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the expected result. Using return with the label like that in `forEach` will have the same behavior with `continue` in Java.

I guess you want it to behave like `break` in Java, in that case you can use `forEach` in combination with [`takeWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-while.html)

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).takeWhile { it != 3 }.forEach {
        print(it)
    }
    print(" done with takeWhile") 
}
```

The result then will be

```
12 done with takeWhile
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is expected behavior. Linked page also has a solution for what you looking for.

```
fun main() {
 run loop@{
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
        if (it == 3) return@loop // non-local return from the lambda passed to run
        print(it)
    }
 }
 print(" done with nested loop")
}
```

Comment: it's good answer too because it shows how use `break` and `continue` in the same `forEach`